# How to build Meteor Templates at runtime?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

Can I dynamically build templates on the server and send the result to clients? I found SpacebarsCompiler.compile() returns a string representing render function, but how to convert it to a template?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this,

```
/**
* @contextObject the object you want to evaluate in your template
* @templateName the name of you template <template name="">
* return html rendered.
*/

function renderTemplate(contextObject, templateName){
   return Blaze.toHTML(Blaze.With(contextObject, function() { return Template[templateName]; }));
}
```

I don't Im been using this in the client side I don't sure if will work on the server side but you could give it a try.

if you have a template html like

```
<template name="thisIsMyTemplateName">
  <div>
    {{name}}
  </div>
</template>
```

then if you have an object like `var myobject = { name : "my name" }`

you could use the function like

`myHtml = renderTemplate(myobject, "thisIsMyTemplateName");`

you will get in return the plain html that you could append or do whatever you want like

`$(document).append(myhtml);`

Comment: I'm stuck with "Template[templateName]", haven't found a way to convert a raw template string as "<div>{{name}}</div>" to a template object.